# How to copy pandas value to another sheet cell?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv, copy

How could I copy a cell value from one sheet (currently a float) to another sheet that has a blank cell (NaN)?  Below are the steps I've tried.

**For Example;** I have this value (510.0):

```
>>> parcel_csv[parcel_csv.PID == '570-177736'].LANDUSE
341817    510.0
Name: LANDUSE, dtype: float64
```

I want it to be assigned here:

```
>>> df.loc[df['Parcel ID']=='570-177736',['Land Use']]
Land Use
0      NaN
```

Based on other questions, this should work:

```
>>> df.loc[df['Parcel ID']=='570-177736',['Land Use']] = parcel_csv[parcel_csv.PID == '570-177736'].LANDUSE
```

I still seem to end up with NaN.  So I tried assigning a value first:

```
>>> df.loc[df['Parcel ID']=='570-177736',['Land Use']] = '111.0'
>>> df.loc[df['Parcel ID']=='570-177736',['Land Use']]
  Land Use
0    111.0
```

Tried the 'copy' again:

```
    >>> df.loc[df['Parcel ID']=='570-177736',['Land Use']] = parcel_csv[parcel_csv.PID == '570-177736'].LANDUSE
```

and ended up with NaN again:

```
>>> df.loc[df['Parcel ID']=='570-177736',['Land Use']]
  Land Use
0      NaN
```

Using .loc on the source cell results in the same thing:

```
>>> parcel_csv.loc[parcel_csv.PID == '570-177736'].LANDUSE
341817    510.0
Name: LANDUSE, dtype: float64
>>> df.loc[df['Parcel ID']=='570-177736',['Land Use']] = parcel_csv.loc[parcel_csv.PID == '570-177736'].LANDUSE
>>> df.loc[df['Parcel ID']=='570-177736',['Land Use']]
  Land Use
0      NaN
```

1. Why can't I copy the value over?
2. Why is the 'Name' and 'dtype' not
   being displayed in the 'destination cell?'  Is that info important?

Python 3.6.7

Thank you!

Comment: Could you post your two dataframes because when I tried assigning it worked well

Comment: The file I'm writing to is a .xlsx and the source data is a csv file that has +10k lines.

sample of the destination .xlsx:
`>>> df
      Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 0.1      Structure Address  ... Mailing Country Land Use  Transfer Date
0              0             0  467  BRANDING IRON DR  ...             NaN      NaN            NaN
1              1             1     5576  DEER HILL DR  ...             NaN      NaN            NaN`

Comment: Here's a few lines from the source csv:
`>>> parcel_csv
               PID    AEXMLND    AEXMBLD    AEXMTOT    APPRLND    APPRBLD    APPRTOT    AUDMAP  AUDRTG  ...                     HEIGHT  NOSTORY  YEARBLT PROPTYP                       WALL  TIFMLND    TIFMBLD       POINT_X        POINT_Y
0       010-000001        0.0        0.0        0.0    11300.0    73300.0    84600.0      H001   71.00  ...                     DUPLEX     20.0   1900.0     NaN                     STUCCO  30700.0    87400.0  1.828201e+06  721773.867180
`

Comment: I tried another value as well and have had no improvement: `>>> df.loc[df['Parcel ID']=='570-257136',['Land Use']] = parcel_csv[parcel_csv.PID == '570-257136'].LANDUSE
>>> df.loc[df['Parcel ID']=='570-257136',['Land Use']]
    Land Use
11       NaN
>>> parcel_csv[parcel_csv.PID == '570-257136'].LANDUSE
350338    510.0
Name: LANDUSE, dtype: float64`

Comment: @Sumanth what version of python are you using?

Comment: it seems my source file dtype is a float64 (csv file) while the desination cell/file is an object.  Currently looking into that.
`>>> df.dtypes['Land Use']
dtype('O')`

Comment: My version is 3.6.7 and its working fine. I just tried creating a dummy data with a Nan value and replaced it with float value.